# Why code in console is not work after filter interactions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

Recently, I have seen an amazing issue in a SPA web page. When I write a code using chrome developer console, it works once. When I change filter interactions, that code does not work.
Here is site link: https://www.butlins.com/latest-offers/prices.aspx?start=08/2017

My simple testing code is given below:
Thanks, it works but this code is work twice. Why?

```
function updateChanges(){
$("a#whatsOnLink").css({"position": "absolute" ,"margin-top": "110px", "margin-left": "-50px"});
  $("p.latest-type").append("<p class='someText'><b>2 Adults and 2 Children</b></p>");
  $("p.someText").css({"font-size": "12px","margin-top": "10px"});
  $("p.latest-type").css({"font-size": "16px"});
  $("a.button.bookingEngine.button-red").css({"margin-top": "-10px"});
  $('.latest-offer-price').each(function(el){
    var data = $(this).text().substring(1);
    $(this).text('£'+(data*4));
  });
}

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
  setTimeout(updateChanges,30)
});

updateChanges();
```

When I write code in console and press enter, append and calculation is made twice.

Furthermore, I change filter interactions, DOM element flashes with violate colour. I don't know why it is caused.

So, What is the reason for behaviour it ?

Why does DOM element flash with violate colour when filter interaction ?

Have any solution to fix it ?

Comment: Probably because that section of the dom gets rebuilt when you change the filters

Comment: The dom elements are updating when you apply the filters, removing the style you applied

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix it ?

Comment: For css.. you could inject a new style tag instead

Comment: How? I don't want to inject code again.

Comment: @Engr.TanbirHasan I'm not sure what the "issue" is. You are locally overwriting a instance of a page using the console where the page is reloaded, as per network tab, when you interact with it's filters. I'm failing to understand what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: @Fran I want that I write a code from console and it will work after filter interactions, but it works once since it is a SPA web page.

Comment: @Engr.TanbirHasan What is your question? If you are asking why a SPA page overwrites your local changes you have the answer already, interacting with filters reloads the DOM elements re-initializing the Styles. You can see the request being made in the Network tab. I don't understand why you must stop the style from refreshing and what you are trying to achieve. Just run your local command again...

Comment: @Engr.TanbirHasan Inspect the Network tab as you change filters where you can see the XHR requests being made that reload the content.

Comment: Yes @Fran, I have seen it, xhr request are increased when I change filter.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting a new `<style>` tag instead. If it is really an SPA then the rule should stay there after the filters are applied. If the page does a full reload you would need to run new code after each new page loads

```
let rule ='a.button.bookingEngine.button-red{background-color: blue}'   

$('head').append($('<style>', {text:rule}))
```

The css rules for that page have very specific selectors.

An alternative is to hook into their jQuery ajax and use `ajaxSuccess` global which will fire after any ajax request succeeds

```
function updateBtns(){
   $("a.button.bookingEngine.button-red").css({"background-color": "blue"})
}

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
  setTimeout(updateBtns,30)
});

updateBtns()
```

Comment: Well it may not be an SPA. Does the page reload when filters change?

Comment: no, it does not reload.But your code is exist in head after filter actions.

Comment: Can you see that style tag in dev tools elements inspector after the filters are applied? Might need to add `!important` also. inspect the styles for those elements in dev tools inspector

Comment: This works `function updateBtns(){
$("a.button.bookingEngine.button-red").css({"background-color": "blue"})
}

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
  setTimeout(updateBtns,50)
});

updateBtns()`

Comment: @Charlitfl Your code works but my code (I update my code sample) is work twice, why?

Comment: They may have secondary calls also. I have not spent any time analyzing all the network requests